# Setting a different height for only the last row in the table, is there a more efficient way?

Tags: ios, uitableview

All rows but the last are the same height in the table. If we forget that last row, in normal circumstances I'd set the table view's height like so:

```
[self.tableView setRowHeight:40.0f];
```

However if I want the last row to be a different height, I'd implement the delegate method `heightForRowAtIndexPath` which would then be called for all index paths. This seems quite expensive and could effect performance for >1000 rows of data.

I don't see any other way, but will remain optimistic until I get feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement footer view for the table and implement the delegate,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Check if the footer view can satisfy your requirement. If you cannot use footer view, you might have to implement the table view's delegate method for setting row height as mentioned in your question. It will not cause any performance hit unless you do some expensive operation there.

Comment: Thanks, but this won't do the trick in my case. I specifically need to alter the height of the last cell. Unless this method can do that somehow?

Comment: @sooper, This works only if you add the last cell as the footer view of the last section. Or you can consider adding as tableview's footer view. Only other way to do this is by implementing the delegate method as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're only returning one height or another, based on a single if statement, it probably won't be that expensive. Method calls are pretty cheap. If you were performing some calculation (typically, calculating a variable height based on the length of text in a row) then you'd see a performance hit. The method is only called when the tableView is reloaded, so scrolling performance won't be an issue.

You should always use the natural framework methods first and check performance, rather than assuming something is going to be slow and making a complex workaround. Like the man said, premature optimisation and all that.

Also, if you have over 1000 rows in your table, you'd better have an index on the side or that will be unusable.

Comment: I've tried it with about 2000 rows and I haven't noticed any lag, but my worry lies with devices I don't have like the 3GS. I think I'll just use the delegate method and avoid reloading the table as much as possible. The table is indexed! Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

```
No you can implement this by specifying different height for different rows as per your requirement.

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == [YourArray count]-1)
    {

        return CustomHeightYouNeedForYourCell;
    }

    return DefaultheightForAllCells;
}
```

Comment: He is aware of this method and he wants know if there is any other way to do it. Check his question _"However if I want the last row to be a different height, I'd implement the delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath which would then be called for all index paths. This seems quite expensive and could effect performance for >1000 rows of data."_